# Find closest match of coordinates in two data frames

Tags: r, match, closest

I hope you can help me with this question:

I have a data.frame with x and y coordinates and now I want to find the closest matching values on a different data.frame with x and y coordinates. It is important that x&y is considered as one as they are a pair.

values to match:

```
df <- data.frame(lon = c(1.2,2.6,2.4,2.5,4.2),
                 lat = c(2.3,4.6,1.2,3.5,0.6))
```

and now I want to find the closest match of these combinations to

```
ref <- data.frame(lon = c(1:5),
                  lat = c(1:5))
```

But the the values for $lon and $lat always belong together. So basically, I am looking for a combination match. And until now I only found to match a single number:

```
x=c(1:100)
your.number <- 75.89
which(abs(x - your.number) == min(abs(x - your.number)))
```

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: yes. I tried to use this approach:  x=c(1:100)
your.number=57.4
which(abs(x-your.number)==min(abs(x-your.number)))

Comment: But this only works for one number ...

Comment: Please edit your question and put in an example of your dataframe (best by typing `dput(head(df))` into the R console (with `df` being the name of your dataframe) and pasting the output into the question) and an example of the stuff you've tried so far. Right now, your question is much too broad to answer.

Comment: sorry, I edited it .. I hope it is understandable now.

Comment: would you want to consider euclidean distance for your scenario, as there are 2 values involved and because they are co-ordinates it makes more sense

Comment: I don't think I will need that, as I am "just" looking to the closest matching number

Comment: if you need to match a combination then what are you considering? is (2,4) closer to (2,10) or (3,3)?

Answer (score 2):

I have added a solution with the Euclidean distance. I have compared the distance between all pairs and got the least of those.

```
# Sample data:

df<-structure(list(ID=c(1:10), lat = c(1.4, 5.8, 4, 6.5, 5.1, 9.3, 8.6, 8.9, 4.4, 1.8)
                   , lon = c(8.1, 4.8, 7.4, 4.8, 0.4, 5, 6.2, 1, 5, 5.2))
              , .Names = c("ID","lat", "lon"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table","data.frame"))

ref<-structure(list(ID=letters[1:10], lat = c(1:10), lon = c(1:10))
               , .Names = c("ID","lat", "lon"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table","data.frame"))

#Setting to data.table format
setDT(df)
setDT(ref)

#creating a table with cartesian join 
df1<-setkey(df[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[ref[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]

#calculating the Euclidean distance and giving a rank in ascending order of distance
df1[,EuDist:=sqrt((lat-i.lat)^2+(lon-i.lon)^2)][,distRank:=rank(EuDist,ties="random"),by=.(ID)]

#selecting the shortest distance
df1<-df1[distRank==1]
```

Comment: thank you for the solution! But I found a simpler way using gDistance and transforming it to spatial points